# Netezza built insert using dotnet

Tags: c#, asp.net, netezza

In my application, instead of using unix am creating user interface using dotnet with backend netezza.
In this scenario i want to load data from excel to netezza db using nzload.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use external tables instead of nzload and you shouldn't have a problem

1. Convert Excel File to CSV in .net
2. Use external table preferably a transient external table to load to netezza